# Cannot handshake ssl sockets having port 587 and server="smtp.gmail.com"

Tags: java, ssl, handshake, sslhandshakeexception

This code works fine for **PORT=465**.
But for PORT=587, it throws exception "Exception in thread main javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, **plaintext connection?**"

```
package smtpClient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.net.ssl.HandshakeCompletedEvent;
import javax.net.ssl.HandshakeCompletedListener;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

class TLS_Mime_G {
    static final int PORT = 587;
    static String REMOTEHOST = "smtp.gmail.com";

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NamingException, KeyManagementException {

        SSLSocketFactory ssf = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) ssf.createSocket(REMOTEHOST, PORT);

        socket.setEnabledProtocols(socket.getSupportedProtocols());
        socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(socket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
        socket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new MyTLSHandshakeListener());
        socket.startHandshake();//Throws Error 

        System.out.println("Connected to " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());

    }
}

class MyTLSHandshakeListener implements HandshakeCompletedListener {
    public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Handshake succesful!");
        System.out.println("Cipher suite used: " + e.getCipherSuite());

    }
}
```

/*
Supported Protocols: SSLv2Hello
Supported Protocols: SSLv3
Supported Protocols: TLSv1
Supported Protocols: TLSv1.1
Supported Protocols: TLSv1.2
Enabled Protocols: TLSv1
Enabled Protocols: TLSv1.1
Enabled Protocols: TLSv1.2
*/

Comment: Could it be because one of the ports is SSL (465) and the other is TLS(587) and ypur library does not support TLS? Maybe different settings are needed...

Comment: No. I did check the supported & enabled protocols

Comment: TLS is supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

465 is 'implicit' TLS-formerly-SSL; you connect at the TCP level, then immediately and always start a TLS connection, and (if successful) then do SMTP over the TLS (over TCP) connection.

587 is 'explicit' TLS-formerly-SSL; you connect at the TCP level and start doing SMTP by reading the server announcement and doing at least an EHLO command and response (and possibly/optionally others), then do a STARTTLS command and check the response and if successful THEN start a TLS connection over the existing TCP connection and (if successful) then do SMTP over the TLS over TCP connection. [Have a look at rfc 3207.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3207)

Your exception already told you this; it indicates you have connected to a server that is not (yet) doing SSL/TLS but is instead doing plaintext -- in this case SMTP in plaintext.

Also, it's a very bad idea to enable all supported versions and ciphersuites; many of them are disabled by default *because* they are not secure. Although SSLv3 is broken by POODLE(!) in this particular case it's okay because gmail (quite correctly) will never negotiate it; OTOH enabling the anonymous suites like ECDH_anon_AES* allows an active attacker to easily intercept, read and/or alter your supposedly secure email.

Or just use javamail, which already implements all of those options and more *correctly*.

Comment: I get the point that STARTTLS is not active on port:587. But how am I supposed to give STARTTLS command?? When I give EHLO command in SSLSocket outputstream, I get the same exception.... So how do I make the server do SSL/TLS instead of doing plaintext?? (and I'm not allowed to use javamail)

Comment: @Shashank STARTTLS is used on 587 for some servers including this one; it is _automatic SSL/TLS_ that is not used. As I said, open a TCP (plaintext) connection -- i.e. `java.net.Socket` -- NOT a TLS connection. Do the EHLO and STARTTLS over the TCP connection. After checking the responses indicate success, then start a TLS connection over the existing TCP connection by using the createSocket overload documented at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#createSocket-java.net.Socket-java.lang.String-int-boolean-